# passing session to a hidden field in a iframe on the same domain

Tags: php, session, iframe

I am using this code

> ```
>   session_start();
>
>   if (!isset($_SESSION["origURL"]))
>     $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
>
> $referrer = $_SESSION["origURL"];
> if(preg_match("/[\.\/](google|yahoo|bing|geegain|mywebsearch|ask|alltheweb)\.[a-z\.]{2,5}[\/]/i",$referrer,$search_engine)){
> $referrer_query = parse_url($referrer);
> $referrer_query = $referrer_query["query"];
> $q = "[q|p]"; //Yahoo uses both query strings, I am using switch() for each search engine
> preg_match("/".$q."=(.*?)&/",$referrer,$keyword);
> $_SESSION["SEKW"]  = urldecode($keyword[1]);
> }
> ?>
> ```

to track referral keywords and  I call this in to a hidden field of my forms which works great.

My problem is I have had to change my form to an iframe and I can no longer call the session now as the form is in a iframe.

so i had

domain.com/myform.php ( every thing worked )

I am now using an iframe from

domain.com/forms/form.php

to place my form into

domain.com/myform.php

I hope I have explained my self correctly

Answer (score 0):

if understand your question correctly.

You can pass the variable by using something like :

```
domain.com/forms/form.php?variablename=variablevalue
```

Hope this help.